# Placing three mathematical formulas next to each other

Tags: math-mode, align, displaystyle

I am new to LaTeX, so please be kind to me. :)  I would like to place three mathematical formulas next to each other but I don't seem to get it working.

This is how far I have got up to now:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hspace{1cm} \vspace{0.2cm}
\(\displaystyle \widetilde{y_i}=bx_i+a \)  \hspace{3cm}\\
$\widetilde{y_i}$ \ldots vorhergesagter Wert \\
$b$ \ldots slope (Steigung der Regressionsgerade) \\ 
$a$ \ldots intercept (Gerade schneidet y-Achse, an der Stelle x=0) \\

        \end{tabular}
    \vspace{0.22cm}
\begin{center}


    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}{l}

        \( \displaystyle b=\frac{s_{XY}}{s_X^2} \) \\[0.4cm]
        \end{tabular}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                & \( \displaystyle a=\bar{y}-b\bar{x} \) &   \\ [0.4cm] 
            \end{tabular}

    \end{tabular}

\end{center}

    \vspace{0.22cm}
\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like at the moment: 
[image]

I would like to put the formula for `b=sXY...` and the formula for `a=y-b*x` 
higher up so that it is in the same line with the first formula (`y_i= b*x_i+a`).

I hope that you understand my problem and that someone is able to help me.

Thanks a lot already in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 b&=\frac{s_{XY}}{s_X^2} &
 a&=\bar{y}-b\bar{x} 
\end{align}
\end{document}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Text above
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{y_i}&=bx_i+a, & b&=\frac{s_{XY}}{s_X^2}, & \displaystyle a&=\bar{y}-b\bar{x},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{y_i}  &\ldots  \text{vorhergesagter Wert} \\
b  &\ldots \text{slope (Steigung der Regressionsgerade)} \\ 
a  &\ldots \text{intercept (Gerade schneidet $y$-Achse, an der Stelle $x=0$)} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the page margins

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\tilde{y}_i=bx_i+a
\qquad
b=\frac{s_{XY}}{s_X^2}
\qquad
a=\bar{y}-b\bar{x}
\\
\begin{minipage}{0.8\displaywidth}
\begin{itemize}[label=,nosep,leftmargin=0pt]
\item $\tilde{y}_i$ vorhergesagter Wert
\item $b$ slope (Steigung der Regressionsgerade)
\item $a$ intercept (Gerade schneidet $y$-Achse, an der Stelle $x=0$)
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

You can later change your mind about the label in the itemize environment.

With `gather*` we ensure no page break is feasible between the equations and their descriptions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make it easy.

See if this way of alignment suit you :)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Blah blah we have:
\begin{align*}
    \widetilde{y_i}=bx_i+a \qquad\quad b=\frac{s_{XY}}{s_X^2} \qquad\quad a=\bar{y}- b\bar{x}
\end{align*}
\[ % or \(\) for inline mode if you want
    \text{where }\left\{
        \begin{array}{rcl}
            \widetilde{y_i} & \ldots & \text{vorhergesagter Wert}\\
             b              & \ldots & \text{slope (Steigung der Regressionsgerade)}\\
             a              & \ldots & \text{intercept (Gerade schneidet $y$-Achse, an der Stelle $x=0$)}
        \end{array}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys all so so much for your much-appreciated help. My document looks really good now. :)

I have one last question: 
[image]

How can I make the

```
y_i... vorhergesagter Wert, 
b...slope, 
a...intercept AND 
r_i... Residuum, 
y_i... beobachteter Wert, 
\widetilde y_i... vorhergesagter Wert
```

make appear aligned under each other. I would like both parts either to be in the center or on the left.

```
\flushleft \textbf {Die Regressionsgerade:} 

\begin{gather*} 

    \widetilde{y}_i=bx_i+a

    \qquad

    b=\frac{s_{XY}}{s_X^2}

    \qquad

    a=\bar{y}-b\bar{x}

    \\

    \begin{minipage}{0.8\displaywidth}

        \begin{itemize}[label=,nosep,leftmargin=0pt]

            \item $\widetilde{y}_i$ \ldots vorhergesagter Wert

            \item $b$ \ldots slope (Steigung der Regressionsgerade)

            \item $a$ \ldots intercept (Gerade schneidet $y$-Achse, an der Stelle $x=0$) \\[0.4cm]

        \end{itemize}

    \end{minipage}

\end{gather*}

\flushleft \textbf {Residuen:} 

\begin{center}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

    \begin{tabular}{l}

        \hspace{1cm} \vspace{0.2cm}

        \(\displaystyle r_i = y_i - \widetilde{y_i} \)  \hspace{3cm}\\

        $r_i$ \ldots Residuum für Beobachtung $i$\\

        $y_i$ \ldots beobachteter Wert von Person $i$\\

        $\widetilde{y_i}$ \ldots vorhergesagter Wert von Person $i$\\[0.4cm]

    \end{tabular}

\end{center}

\vspace{0.22cm}
```

Thank you so much one more time.

Comment: If you want them to be aligned to the left, why not simply type them as normal text? To make it better, add `\qquad` in front of each of them.